# How to inject a Renderer to SimpleExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use Exoplayer 2.9.0 and Audio 360
There are two renderers:

```
val videoRenderer = MediaCodecVideoRenderer(mActivity, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT)
val audioRenderer = OpusRenderer(mVideoHelper.audio360Sink)
```

I know how to inject it to an Exoplayer Object:

```
val render = arrayOf(videoRenderer, audioRenderer)
Exoplyer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newInstance(render ,DefaultTrackSelector())
```

However, I only use SimpleExoPlayer. I wonder how to do the same for SimpleExoPlayer object?  Alternatively, Is there a way to pass an ExoPlayer to a SimpleExoPlayer object ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SimpleExoPlayer`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.java#L127) gets its `Renderers` off of a [`RendererFactory`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/RenderersFactory.java#L30) which is passed in during SimpleExo initialization. The usual one you see is the [`DefaultRendererFactory`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultRenderersFactory.java).

If you really only need those two `Renderers` then you could pass in your own implementation of the `RendererFactory` which just returns those two. Or you can consider using `DefaultRendererFactory` modifying it.